# Python Beautiful Soup get data from 2 URL's

Tags: python

Good day, I am a student taking python classes. We are now learning about Beautiful Soup and I am having trouble extracting data from 2 tables as you will see in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

list_of_urls = ['https://tradingeconomics.com/albania/gdp-growth-annual',
                'https://trdingeconomics.com/south-africa/gdp-growth-annual']

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in lists_of_urls:
    table = pd.read_html(i, match='Related')
    for row in table:
        if row.loc['Related'] == 'GDP Annual Growth Rate':
            final_df.append(row)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: You're learning about BeautifulSoup but not actually using it in your code. What output are your trying to get from those URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need neither `requests` nor `bs4`. `pd.read_html` does the job.

```
list_of_urls = ['https://tradingeconomics.com/albania/gdp-growth-annual',
                'https://tradingeconomics.com/south-africa/gdp-growth-annual']

data = {}
for i in list_of_urls:
    country = i.split('/')[3]
    df = pd.read_html(i, match='Related')[0]
    data[country] = df.loc[df['Related'] == 'GDP Annual Growth Rate']

df = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                               Related  Last  Previous     Unit Reference
albania      1  GDP Annual Growth Rate  6.99     18.38  percent  Sep 2021
south-africa 1  GDP Annual Growth Rate  1.70      2.90  percent  Dec 2021
```